# juniper advertising smaller subnets with a bigger static route in BGP

Tags: routing, router, bgp, juniper, juniper-junos

I have a /18 in RIB but I would like advertise smaller subnet in BGPfor specific reason to diff ISP etc. Is there a way to do it without creating a null route or static route. Is some way in policy statement I can do this advertisement by matching against the bigger subnet or something?

Comment: Do these smaller subnets exist in your IGP? Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use a nullroute?

Comment: I have a /16 actually on a whole so it is too many /24s to have a null route.

Comment: And they are not in IGP as well. All Traffic just goes to firewall...

Comment: I am not sure I get this right. So with a static or null there is no way is that right ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, a route needs to exist to be able to advertise it. Either because it's in your IGP, or because you add statics or nullroutes. I fail to see why adding those routes is such a challenge though.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The typical way to solve this *would* be to create static routes or nullroutes which you then advertise to your upstream ISP's. You need to have a route for them in your routing table to be able to announce the prefix to your peers.

However, you don't *need* to deaggregate your /16 into /24's. You can use larger networks (/21's for example), or you can choose to announce the /16 as the overlapping aggregated prefix and select a few /24's for which you want to advertise a different preference.